# Simple Addition in php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, addition

Ok so I am wondering if there is a simple way to make Addonetothis in my code to add it's current INT + 1 whenever this code is ran?

```
<?php
$server = "localhost";
$user = "**********";
$pass = "**********";
$dbname = "**********";

//Creating connection for mysqli

$conn = new mysqli($server, $user, $pass, $dbname);

//Checking connection

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed:" . $conn->connect_error);
}

$article_id = $_GET['id'];

if ( ! is_numeric($article_id))
    die("Looks like you are lost!  <a href='#'>Back to Home</a> ");

$sql = "UPDATE Example SET addonetothis='+ 1' WHERE `ID` =$article_id";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    header("Refresh:1; url=example.php?id=$article_id");
    echo "Thank you!";
} else {
    echo "Error" . $sql . "<br/>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Is the badly styled name Addonetothis  an int or a varchar?

Comment: That's just a quick example I changed all the names from original code due to personal reasons.  (It is a INT)

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) If you are using mysqli then try using `parameter binding` and `prepared statements`.

Comment: I rolled the question back to a previous revision. What you edited https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47255827/5 after the question was solved wasn't required. You can't do what you did, it doesn't work that way here. Accepting the answer is all you needed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you would have seen that...

```
$sql = "UPDATE Example SET Addonetothis='+ 1' WHERE `ID` =$article_id";
```

will blow up if Addonetothis is defined as an integer in your Database table as you are setting it to a string.

What you are looking for is something like...

```
$sql = "UPDATE Example SET AddOneToThis = AddOneToThis + 1 WHERE `ID` =$article_id";
```

Comment: That worked perfect, thank you!  Looking now I see what you mean, I completely overlooked that I was setting a string with ' '...

Comment: Yes, I've not delved into the possible SQL Injection issues and other traps as others have been commenting... So please read the other comments regarding this.